# creating url with sprintf creates wrong url

Tags: matlab, url, printf

I am trying to create a ulr using sprintf. To open various websites I changed part of the URL using sprintf. Now the following code writes 3times the url instread of replacing part of the url????Any suggestions?Many thanks!!

```
current_stock = 'AAPL';

current_url = sprintf('http://www.finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=%d&ty=c&ta=0&p=d',current_stock)
web(current_url, '-browser')
```

%d should be the place holer for appl. Result is :

```
http://www.finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=65&ty=c&ta=0&p=dhttp://www.finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=65&ty=c&ta=0&p=dhttp://www.finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=80&ty=c&ta=0&p=dhttp://www.finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=76&ty=c&ta=0&p=d
```

Comment: may you post the result you are expecting?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you're using `%d` for a value that is clearly a string? You should be using `%s`.

The reason you're seeing what you're seeing is that it appears to be giving you a copy of your format string for *each character* in the `AAPL` string.

You can see that the differences lie solely in the `?t=XX` bit, with `XX` being, in sequence, 65, 65, 80 and 76, the ASCII codes for the four letters in your string:

```
                                   vv
http://www.finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=65&ty=c&ta=0&p=d
http://www.finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=65&ty=c&ta=0&p=d
http://www.finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=80&ty=c&ta=0&p=d
http://www.finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=76&ty=c&ta=0&p=d
                                   ^^
```

Whether that's a feature or bug in MatLab <sup>(a)</sup>, I couldn't say for sure, but I suspect it'll fix itself if you just use the correct format specifier.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> It's probably a feature since it does similarly intelligent stuff with other mismatches, as per [here](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html):

> If you apply a string conversion (`%s`) to integer values, MATLAB converts values that correspond to valid character codes to characters. For example, `'%s'` converts `[65 66 67]` to `ABC`.

Answer (score 0):

I would follow this easy way:

```
current_stock = 'AAPL';
current_url = ['http://www.finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=%d&ty=c&ta=0&p=d',current_stock];
web(current_url,'-browser')
```

That redirected me to a valid webpage.

Comment: It looks like Dominion Resources is peaking, sell!